# How do I retrieve the file Property metadata in Windows from within QT?

Tags: c++, windows, file, qt, metadata

I couldn't find a good answer for this.

What is the code for looking at the metadata of an executable file, like Description and Company, or the API reference guide for doing such a thing?

I have looked through [QFileInfo](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html), but the code can only read and output the basic cross platform information like names, path, and times.

Comment: I don't know if you can access these with Qt, but the Windows API functions to get that information are GetFileVersionInfo [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003(v=vs.85).aspx) and VerQueryValue [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a Qt'ish way to do it, because such information is not really cross-platform. As it was mentioned in comments best way to use windows API for this.

I faced once similar problem when I had to handle all this information within cross-platform project. So goal was to keep all metadata available through cross-platform builds as well as showing it properly on Windows File Properties dialog. Most fast solution I was able to come up with is to define all this information via #define in one version.h, so it became to be available within software and reuse same defines in windows RC file which included version.h and was included itself in the .pro under win32 condition.